# Как получить класс, который вызвал метод другого класса?

Tags: python, ооп

У меня есть 2 класса:

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def log(self, log):  # Этот класс должен перехватить имя класса, который его вызовет
        with open(self.name, "a+") as log_file:
            log_file.write(log)

        return log


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Logger("log.txt")

    def log_some(self, message):
        print(message)
        self.logger.log(message)

        return message
```

И мне необходимо, чтобы класс `Logger` при вызове из другого класса метода `log()` смог получить имя класса, вызвавшего метод. 
Есть путь получения имени класса, в котором метод определён

```
self.__class__.__name__
```

Но он в данном случае будет мне бесполезен. Если ещё варианты?

Comment: Если вы хотите логировать ошибки, то возможно пригодится [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html). Там есть полезные плюшки.

Comment: As per Sergey Gornostaev, лучше передавать в метод класса информацию о вызывающем его другом классе в явном виде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше бы передавать в конструктор `Logger` информацию о вызывающем классе. Но можно и организовать разного рода костыли на основе анализа стека вызовов:

```
import inspect

def get_caller_name():
    frames = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe(), 3)
    if len(frames) > 1:
        info = frames[1]
        args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(info.frame)
        obj = values.get('self')
        if obj is not None:
            return '{}.{}'.format(obj.__class__.__name__, info.function)
        return info.function
```

Comment: О! Как раз подобную чорную магия я подозревал и опасался ) Не то, что я бы порекомендовал использовать - но респект!

Answer (score 0):

Краткий ответ: **никак**

## Развернутый ответ

Смотрим на сигнатуру `Logger.log`:

```
class Logger:
    .....
    def log(self, log):  # Этот класс должен перехватить имя класса, который его вызовет
        with open(self.name, "a+") as log_file:
            log_file.write(log)

    return log
```

И мы видим, что все ООП - это единственный `self`, который будет указывать на экземпляр `Logger`.

Указания на caller - нет, и соотственно .. ответ: **никак**.

## Чорная магия

Если есть желание почувствовать себя могучим магом и чародеем и навсегда прославиться среди коллег - можно, конечно, попробовать что-нибудь покопать с `sys.settrace`, манипуляцией с фреймами, кастомизировать неймспейсы `globals`/`locals`, черт побери - дизасм и копаться в байткоде.

Но: я никакого простого рецепта для такой магии не знаю и не рекомендую (кроме как для повышения квалификации).